# Execute multiple independent statements in SQLAlchemy Core?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy Core to run a few independent statements. **The  statements are to separate tables and unrelated**. Because of that I can't use the standard `table.insert()` with multiple dictionaries of params passed in. Right now, I'm doing this:

```
sql_conn.execute(query1)
sql_conn.execute(query2)
```

Is there any way I can run these in one shot instead of needing two back-and-forths to the db? I'm on MySQL 5.7 and Python 2.7.11.

Comment: Why would be a good idea run two statements together? Or what would be the gain?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi One round-trip to the DB instead of two.

Comment: If one statement fail, no one will be executed. With independent statements, you have more control and is easier to debug.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi That's a trade off you have to make in order to extract better performance. As an example, SQLAlchemy ORM batches queries.

Comment: Maybe, this is not a good way to follow. SQLAlchemy has a good [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/faq/performance.html) about performance

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Batching queries together is very much a valid way to reduce latency. Performance is not limited to optimizing how long a query takes to run.

Comment: @Eli, doing it on 2 separate connections in parallel is not suitable? Are you familiar with the SQLA ORM Session?

Comment: @creativeChips That would require an extra connection + async to manage. If you're in a prod environment with many boxes, adding an extra connection per box would be a lot of extra connections and could hit DB limitations. It's not a terrible solution, but it feels like an over-engineered one when there's no reason you should be able to just send two queries in one shot over the same connection.

Comment: @Eli If you're looking to optimize perf, two parallel ops will actually allow the DB to insert simultaneously since they execute on different tables.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [Transaction](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Transaction):

```
with engine.connect() as sql_conn:
    with sql_conn.begin():
        sql_conn.execute(query1)
        sql_conn.execute(query2)
```

There is an implicit `sql_conn.commit()` above (when using the context manager) which commits the changes to the database in one trip.  If you want to do it explicitly, it's done like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test")
connection = engine.connect()
trans = connection.begin()
connection.execute(text("insert into x (a, b) values (1, 2)"))
trans.commit()
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#basic-usage

While this is mostly geared towards creating real database transactions, it has a useful side effect for your use case, where it will maintain a "virtual" transaction in SQLAlchemy, see this link for more info:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#session-level-vs-engine-level-transaction-control

The Session tracks the state of a single “virtual” transaction at a time, using an object called SessionTransaction. This object then makes use of the underlying Engine or engines to which the Session object is bound in order to start real connection-level transactions using the Connection object as needed.

> This “virtual” transaction is created automatically when needed, or
> can alternatively be started using the Session.begin() method. To as
> great a degree as possible, Python context manager use is supported
> both at the level of creating Session objects as well as to maintain
> the scope of the SessionTransaction.

The above describes the ORM functionality but the link shows that it has parity with the Core functionality.

Comment: Isn't it possible by sqla async?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides several techniques; you decide which fits:

Case 1 -- 2 round trips to the server:

```
query1;
query2;
```

Case 2 -- 1 round trip to `CALL` a stored procedure like the following:

```
-- one-time declaration (overhead not included):
CREATE PROCEDURE both
BEGIN;
    query1;
    query2;
END;

-- per invocation (1 round trip)
CALL both();
```

Caveat:  If you need to parameterize the call, especially with a variable number of operands, it gets messy.

Case 3:  Multiple `INSERTs` into a single table -- batch insert is 1 round trip.

```
INSERT INTO t (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (11,22), ...;
```

(There are various other techniques for multiple `DELETEs`, `UPDATEs`, etc, involving a single table.)

Case 4:  "Atomicity" is needed (due to possible conflicts with other processes) -- multiple round trips.

```
START TRANSACTION;
query1;
query2;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score -1):

It is neither wise, nor practical, to run two queries at once.  *I am referring to having a single call to the server with two SQL statements one after another:  "SELECT ...; SELECT ...;"*

It is not wise allowing such give hackers another way to do nasty things via "SQL Injection".

On the other hand, it is possible, but not necessarily practical.  You would create a Stored Procedure that contains any number of related (or unrelated) queries in it.  Then `CALL` that procedure.  There some things that *may* make it impractical:

- The only way to get data in is via a finite number of scalar arguments.
- The output comes back as multiple resultsets; you need to code differently to see what happened.

Roundtrip latency is *insignificant* if you are on the same machine with the MySQL server.  It can usually be ignored even if the two servers are in the same datacenter.  Latency becomes important when the client and server are separated by a long distance.  For cross-Atlantic latency, we are talking over 100ms.  Brazil to China is about 250ms.  (Be glad we are no living on Jupiter.)

Comment: If the queries are being defined by me, and we're doing proper parameterization, there's no added risk of SQL Injection. Even 50ms extra time for us is a big deal, which is why I asked the question. Definitely don't want to use stored procedures for this, nor theoretically should I have to when I can very easily send both queries at once just using raw SQL instead of SQLAlchemy Core. Because of that, the question is specifically about doing this through SQLAlchemy Core.

Comment: @Eli - The protection comes form disallowing multi-query.  Hackers love to turn one query into many; this throttles them some.  Example - close off the quotes and do something nasty: `"; DROP ...` as part of what should have been just a string.

Comment: That's a parameterization issue, which is what I'm referring to above. If people are doing correct parameterization, that prevents hackers doing stacked queries. That's a separate issue from whether we should be able to run multiple queries in one shot from SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I added a new first paragraph -- There had been two ways to interpret my Answer.

Comment: -1, This answer has a lot of unnecessary [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt) about "hackers" and "insignificant latency". What OP is looking for is a transaction.